# Get Temp folder path or version of Dynamics NAV in C/AL?

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics

Is there any CodeUnit or Function in Dynamics NAV which I can use to receive...

- the installed NAV build number (example: 10.0.15601.0) or
- the path to the client's temp NAV folder?

I would like to access this information for something I am doing in a .NET Add-In where I want to check the temp path in case certain dlls are not installed on the client but have been copied from the NAV server to the client's temp folder.

Getting the temp path from NAV would be very convenient, but even the version number would already be enough to build the path in C# code.

Edit: Working with Dynamics NAV 2015 to 2017 in this case.

Comment: http://www.dynamics.is/?p=772

Comment: @Smartis That's quite neat already. Is there also an option to get the path to the Add-Ins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Getting Client's Temp Folder

There is the `Codeunit 419` which provides the function `ClientTempFileName(",")`.
It should lead you directly to the clients `%TEMP%` path.

---

## Deploy Client Control Add-in's

*The last time i did this was with **NAV2013 R2**. But after doing some googling i found out, my old way is depreciated in the new versions. Also there was a `*.bat` file solution for this also somewhere around the Interwebz.*

---

But according to [Solution Systems](http://www.solsyst.com/single-post/2015/02/17/Control-AddIn-dlls-Files-in-Microsoft-Dynamics-NAV-2015), this automated deployment of `Client Control Add-in` isn't necessary anymore.

> With Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2015 there comes one feature in Add-In files area – you do not need manually to copy add-in dll to client: when client doesn’t find it, NAV copies add-in from server.

I can't tell you for sure, if this works, but according to them you have to place your `.dll`, on the server into:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\71\RoleTailored Client\Add-ins\
```

And the client should download the `.dll`'s in the correct NAV Temp Folder.

Important is to make sure your Client Add-In is working before placing it on the Server Folder.

### MSDN

The [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983803(v=nav.90).aspx) about this tells us the same:

> If the control add-in assembly is updated and its version number changes, Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server will deploy the updated assembly to the client computer the next time that the client requests the assembly. The updated assembly is put in a subfolder of the %TEMP%\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\Add-Ins folder, where the subfolder has the assembly's version number as its name. This implementation means that you do have to remove the older versions of assemblies that are stored on the client computer.

So no worry about RTC versions on the client computer.

Comment: Yes, this is all correct so far. The Add-Ins are indeed automatically copied, which is very useful for NAV Code and automatic resolving in C#, Should mention though that under "%TEMP%\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\Add-Ins" one folder is created for each NAV build you worked with (at least for NAV 2016 and 2017 I can say for sure). That's why i asked for the version number, though I guess you would normally not work with multiple versions. Anyways, with this info I should be able to solve my problem.